# NOOBQ- Can't create a function with two variables

Tags: r

```
w <- function(x,y) { 

  ((2*x*y+y^4)/(x^2))
                      
}  #Function we need to solve
w(5)
```

Error in w(5) : argument "y" is missing, with no default

This error occurs but y is a function too and i created y before but this error occurred again.

Comment: @Quinten has given you a start. Since you’ve now told us that `y` is a function, you need to pass it to your function (or provide a default) thus: `w(5, myFunc)` and call it within `w` like so: `y()`. It would help us to help you if we had a *minimal reproducible example*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you need to set `*` to multiply in R like this:

```
w <- function(x,y) {
  
  (2*x*y+y^4)/(x^2)
  
}
```

The error says `y` is missing because you only give `x` a value. So if you want this function to work, you need to set a value for `y` for example `w(5,1)`:

```
> w(5, 1)
[1] 0.44
```